# How do I move cells according to a sort when a cell is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, ios13

I am look for a way to move a cell when tapped to its place according to a sort.

I have Googled and not found much and personally have never done something like this before.

This is my sort

```
 let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.name), ascending: true)
```

This is my `didSelectRow`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = fetchedRC.object(at:indexPath)

    item.isComplete.toggle()

    do {
        try context.save()
        //tableView.deselectRow(at: [indexPath.row], animated: true)
        //tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I would like for selected cells to be crossed out (I have handled already) and moved to the bottom of the tableView which is what my sort is doing.  The sort only works when loaded, as expected, but I would like to move the cell that gets selected to its respective place after the initial appearance of the table.

EDIT:
    I decided to test the sort and it was set to my names instead of my `isComplete` field so it now moves them accordingly but now it does not cross out the text like it is supposed to do.

Comment: If the table view is driven by a fetched results controller the UI should be updated automatically after the context is saved.

Comment: What part need to be updated?  The whole table view or just the cell?

Comment: If the delegate methods of `NSFetchedResultsController` are implemented those methods update the UI. No need to reload the row(s) manually.

Comment: Ok so remove the `deselectRow` and `reloadRows`?

Comment: In the default implementation both `didChange` methods contain the `insert/delete/update/move` table view methods corresponding to the `NSFetchedResultsChangeType`

Comment: ok.  Can I call the controller for that directly?  If so would this be move? And what new index would I give it?

Comment: Once again, if everything is hooked up correctly the UI is updated automatically according to the sort descriptor after saving the context.

Comment: Ok so then something is not connected correctly because it crosses out the cells correctly but does not move them according to the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this solution and it seems to work how intended.  All I needed to do was replace my exciting `.move` to this.

```
case .move:
        if indexPath != nil {
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
```